# Why the syntax error throw by redeclare a variable using let in io.js can not be catched

Tags: io.js

This problem is weird io.js 1.0.4

```
var assert = require('assert');

assert.throws(function(){
  let foo = 'foo';
  let foo = 'foo';
  },SyntaxError
) // test doesn't pass

assert.throws(function(){
  throw new SyntaxError('error')
  },SyntaxError

) // test pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SyntaxError`s are thrown at parse time, before the function has run at all, e.g.

```
console.log('something something');

function fn(){
   let x = 4;
   let x = 5;
}
```

This will throw. Note that not only does `console.log` not print anything, but `fn` isn't even being run. So in your case, you can't catch, because the code hasn't even started executing yet.

Note, since `parse time` is key here, you can catch this kind of thing when the file is being required.

#### entry.js

```
try {
    require('./module-file')
} catch (e){
    if (e instanceof SyntaxError){
        console.log('There was a syntax error');
    }
}
```

module-file.js

```
"use strict";

function fn(){
    let x = 4;
    let x = 5;
}
```

Comment: it makes sense to me, thank you. So for a 'real syntax error', there's no way to catch programmatically aren't there?

Comment: @mko Expanded my answer a bit for one case where you can catch it.